# Draw Image with fixed height and width jetpack compose canvas using drawImage()

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-canvas, jetpack-compose-drawscope

How can I draw an image on a Jetpack Compose canvas while ensuring that the image fits perfectly within the entire canvas width and height, especially when the resolution of the image is significantly larger than the canvas size? I would like to reduce the image's size to match the canvas dimensions.

```
@Composable
fun Item(
    imageResId: Int,
    parallaxOffset: Float,
    pagerHeight: Dp,
    screenWidth: Dp,
    density: Float,
    scaleFactor: Float,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    imageCornerRadius: Dp = 24.dp,
    imageHeight: Dp = 250.dp,
) {
    // Load the image bitmap
    val imageBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = imageResId)
   

  
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        // Card composable for the item
        Box(modifier = modifier
            .graphicsLayer {
                scaleX = scaleFactor
                scaleY = scaleFactor
            }
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(imageCornerRadius))) {
            
            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(250.dp)
                    .clip(shape)
            ) {)
                translate(left = parallaxOffset * density) {
                    // Draw the image
                    drawImage(
                        image = imageBitmap,
                        dstOffset = IntOffset(-xOffset.toIntPx(density), 0),
                    )
                }
            }

        }
       
    }

}
```

[image: Canvas Image]

Comment: Do you wish to get dimensions of a Bitmap before creating and set its size as big as  Canvas or draw your image inside Canvas to fit it perfectly while not manipulating Bitmap itself?

Comment: I want it to be fit perfectly or crop centred inside the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dstSize` param to draw whole canvas if you want to.

`srcSize` how big image itself should be drawn
`dstSize` how big the draw area should be inside canvas

By default `dstSize` is equal to `srcSize` and because of this when image is small draw area is smaller than Canvas. And when srcSize is bigger than Canvas dstSize draws it as big as image pixels are but since we can only see screen you only see some part of it as its cropped when image is big. By changing srcOffset you can set which part is drawn in that case as well.

You can test srcSize/Offset, dstSize/Offset params in this tutorial any image you can add to it.

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/fc09f45147e3c49d75b52fb7f0f5b46cfcb78bc9/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter6_graphics/Tutorial6_1_2CanvasBasics2.kt#L331

Result is from a image that is bigger than Canvas. First one draws the section while in second one image is fit into Canvas.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun CanvasScaleTest() {
    val imageBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(R.drawable.sample)

    Column {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().aspectRatio(4/3f).clipToBounds()
        ) {
            drawImage(
                image = imageBitmap,
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().aspectRatio(4/3f).clipToBounds()
        ) {
            val canvasWidth = size.width.toInt()
            val canvasHeight = size.height.toInt()
            drawImage(
                image = imageBitmap,
                dstSize = IntSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the DrawImageWithFixedSize composable to draw an image with a fixed width and height:

```
    @Composable
    fun DrawImageWithFixedSize(imageResId: Int, width: Dp, height: Dp) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val imageDrawable = remember(imageResId) {
            context.resources.getDrawable(imageResId, null)
        }

        val bitmap = remember(imageDrawable) {
            imageDrawable.toBitmap(
                width = (width.value * LocalDensity.current.density).roundToInt(),
                height = (height.value * LocalDensity.current.density).roundToInt()
            )
        }.asImageBitmap()

        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.White)
        ) {
            drawImage(image = bitmap)
        }
    }
```

Where :

```
    DrawImageWithFixedSize(
        imageResId = R.drawable.your_image,
        width = 200.dp,
        height = 150.dp
    )
```